# "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, runtime-error

Exception...

```
<code>Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/pushingpixels/lafwidget/LafWidgetSupport
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pushingpixels.lafwidget.LafWidgetSupport
... 3 more</code>
```

I get this error when trying to use the substance api by pushpixel.

Downloaded from: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.java.net.substance/substance/6.0

I have tried adding the jar to the classpath, it does not work! I am using eclipse.

Comment: you can try using maven for dependency management..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found two group ids.. which one you are expecting. the exception clearly says the dependency from group id org.pushingpixels, but you have org.java.net.substance

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.java.net.substance</groupId>
    <artifactId>substance</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

other from

org.pushingpixels

http://code.google.com/p/bluebell/source/browse/trunk/lib/org/pushingpixels/substance/6.1/substance-6.1.pom?r=183

EDIT- i have found this dependency too , since i dont know right version and maven dependency

http://mavenhub.com/c/org/pushingpixels/lafwidget/LafWidgetSupport/dependency

Comment: Thank you! the error goes away, but the look and feel still doesnt work :(

Comment: @ChrisGray one good news :) , bad news as well. check whether you are using correct version or not..

Comment: I think I am using the correct version. I was following this guide: http://insubstantial.github.io/insubstantial/substance/docs/getting-started.html
It told me to add some VM arguements but when I did I got another error : Error: Could not find or load main class

Answer (score 0):

1. You might not have set the classpath in environment variables

   a. use `-classpath .` instead
2. The `main()` is not in the class you are running.
3. If it's in a package, then you are not running it properly. eg, `hello.Hello` (`pkg.Class`).

Comment: This is how I am running it :
  try {
   UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SubstanceBusinessBlackSteelLookAndFeel());
  } catch(Exception e) {}

Comment: In environment variables what should the name of the variable be?
and should I add this exactly "-classpath ." or replace the "-classpath ." with "-classpath pathToLibrary"?